# Making a JQuery UI Menu close itself after a delay of mouseout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu

I have this situation, represented in a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/j2Y9h/1/

To reproduce my problem :

1. Hover over the Menu to open the menu
2. Hover over a SubMenu item without clicking
3. Get the mouse out of the menu
4. Wait (and don't click anywhere)

You'll notice that the menu never gets closed.

I would like to close the menu after let's say, 5 seconds have elapsed without the mouse coming back to the menu or submenus.

How?

Thanks :)

Comment: menu collapses when i click anywhere thats not the menu. reactively i did this...i'm not sure if this is an issue. i don't know much about `jquery-ui` but you may have to implement it to close when it doesn't see the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that being said, I got a lil' familiar with `jquery-ui` and forged [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2Y9h/2/).

I used:

```
$('#menu').menu();
$('#menu').hover(function(){return false;},function () {
    $('#menu').menu("collapseAll", null, true);
});
```

for my javascript.